# Getting $_GET value within loop

Tags: php

I can't see the problem with this bit of code it seems simple enough, i have a basic webpage:

```
<?php

include('includes/db_connection.php');
include('includes/functions.php');
include('includes/arrays.php');

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Payday Dreams</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="templates/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="templates/css/bootstrap_v3.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
body{background:url(templates/images/bg_sub.png) repeat-x;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/json2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="templates/js/ajax.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background:#cfe4ee;">
<div style="height:100px; background:#000;">
<div style="width:971px; margin:0 auto; color:#ffffff; font-size:13px;">
<div style="text-align:center; padding-top:10px; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; font-family:Arial"> <img src="templates/images/small_lock.png" alt="" style="vertical-align:middle" />&nbsp;Unlock this page to continue! 
<br />
<p class="link_ins">TEST</p>
<div id="_ostatus" style="color:#ffffff;  font-size:14px; font-weight:normal">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="linklocker_wrapper">
<div id="contents" style="margin-top:100px;">
<div class="jumbotron"> 
<div id="offersSection2" style="height:250px; width:570px; margin:25px auto" >

<!-- offer box -->
<div class="offerp_box3" >
<div class="mid" style="height:220px">
<div id="_offers">
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered table-condensed" style="width:530px; background:#ffffff; border:1px solid #cccccc;">
<?php
  // get offers from the database
  $rows = DB::getInstance()->select('SELECT * FROM `offers` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5');   
?>
<?php foreach ($rows as $row) { ?>
<?php
 print_r($_GET);
 $p = $_GET['p'];
 echo $p;
?>
    <tr >
        <td class="offerDiv" title="<?php echo $row['offer_title']; ?>" style="height:30px; vertical-align:middle">
        <div><img src="templates/images/chk.png" alt="" />&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="click.php?c=<?php echo $row['offer_title_id']; ?>&l=&p=<?php echo $p; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['offer_title']; ?></a></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div id="dform" style="display:none; width:90%; text-align:center">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The URL is like this: http://www.site.co.uk/page.php?l=1p=7 what i'm trying to do is get the value of $_GET['p'] and use it within the foreach loop, when i try to print the value out within the loop it's blank but shows fine before it enters the loop, i have racked the brains i can't think of an alternate way of getting that value, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: so where's `$_GET['l']` and  `$_GET['1p']`  ? All I see is `$_GET['p']`.

Comment: please show you output `print_r($_GET)`

Comment: Is the URL typed incorrectly?  You don't have an ampersand seperating l and p.  Should it be http://www.site.co.uk/page.php?l=1&p=7.  Otherwise, $_GET['p'] doesn't exist.

Comment: I never bothered trying to get the $_GET['l'] value yet as i noticed i couldn't get the $_GET['p'] one :)

Comment: Oh my god! it was the ampersand! i spent an hour trying to figure out the error, thanks a lot guys!

Comment: then you won't be able to get the 2nd array if you haven't for the 1st.

Comment: Basic debugging: do `var_dump($_GET)`. you'll probably get something like `Array(1) { "l" => "1p=7" }`, because you're missing a `&` to separate your two key=value pairs.

Comment: this question should be closed as a typo then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your URL correct at your guess? Believably, what you are trying to do is: `http://www.site.co.uk/page.php?l=1&p=7` Notice the **&** in the URL. You had: `http://www.site.co.uk/page.php?l=1p=7`. Was that intentional?

Answer (score 1):

In your URL, the two query string parameters need to be separated by &. It's unable to recognize what p is.

http://www.site.co.uk/page.php?l=1&p=7